# how can i comply with this component test with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I have a component with some props but when i want to test if he rendered, the test failed and i have this error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

this is my component :

```
  render(){
   const character = this.props.character ? this.props.character : null;
   const characterName = this.props.character.name ? 
   this.props.character.name : null;
 const characterStatus = this.props.character.status  ? 
   this.props.character.status : null;

return(
  <TouchableOpacity 
  onPress={() => {}}
  style={styles.item_container}
  >
    <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: character.image}}/>
    <View style={styles.content_container}>
      <View >
        <Text style={styles.name}>{characterName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.status}>{characterStatus}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

And my jest test:

```
 it('renders ListItem without children', () => {
const rendered = renderer.create( <ListItem  /> ).toJSON();
expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
 })
```

how can I pass this test and test correctly if my component is well rendered?

Comment: Your test is failing because `character` is not being passed in the props, therefore is undefined which causes the error you're getting

Comment: @DanielCondeMarin you mean in my test?
if so, how to pass it on correctly?

Comment: You can have `<ListItem character={testCharacter} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems.

Firstly in your component you are doing the following

```
const character = this.props.character ? this.props.character : null;
const characterName = this.props.character.name ? this.props.character.name : null;
```

This is going to cause an undefined error every time the `this.props.character` is null as you will not be able to get the `name` property from the `character` prop. You need to come up with a way of handling the response whenever the `this.props.character` is null. Whether that is returning null for your component or using a default value. The choice is up to you.

Secondly your test is failing because you are not passing the character prop which your component relies on, see the first point above. You need to create an object that is a sample character and pass it to your `ListItem`. Something like this, you can fill in the correct information.

```
it('renders ListItem without children', () => {
  const character = { name: '<CHARACTER_NAME>', image: '<IMAGE_URI>', status: '<CHARACTER_STATUS>'};
  const rendered = renderer.create( <ListItem  character={character}/> ).toJSON();
  expect(rendered).toBeTruthy();
})
```

If you want your test to pass when you don't pass the character prop then you need to put some protections so that nothing is undefined when the character prop is null.

Comment: you're right ! I handled the errors via a default value to my props and the test passes.
But I also remember the object in props to perform a test...
Thank you ;)  !